# Loop through json, with multiple key values (some same value)

Tags: php, json

I've exported some entries from a database which has given me the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "Artist_Title": "17 Hippies",
    "Gallery_Image_Filename": "17Hippies-2011-web.jpg"
  },
  {
    "Artist_Title": "17 Hippies",
    "Gallery_Image_Filename": "christo.jpg"
  },
  {
    "Artist_Title": "17 Hippies",
    "Gallery_Image_Filename": "kiki1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "Artist_Title": "17 Hippies",
    "Gallery_Image_Filename": "17-hippies.jpg"
  },
  {
    "Artist_Title": "17 Hippies",
    "Gallery_Image_Filename": "Photo1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "Artist_Title": "Ann Savoy Trio",
    "Gallery_Image_Filename": "Savoy-Trio-B&W-resize342x.jpg"
  },
  {
    "Artist_Title": "Baghdaddies",
    "Gallery_Image_Filename": "Baghdaddies-(Small).JPG"
  },
  {
    "Artist_Title": "Baghdaddies",
    "Gallery_Image_Filename": "Baghdaddies2.jpg"
  }
]
```

Which has gallery images associated against a post. I've exported the Post Title (Artist_Title) and the Image file name (Gallery_Image_Filename).

One post can have multiple gallery images, the end goal here is to do an foreach and var dump a list like for example

```
wget www.[domain].com/images/17Hippies-2011-web.jpg -O 17-hippies-gallery-1.jpg
wget www.[domain].com/images/christo.jpg -O 17-hippies-gallery-2.jpg
wget www.[domain].com/images/kiki1.jpg -O 17-hippies-gallery-3.jpg
wget www.[domain].com/images/17-hippies.jpg -O 17-hippies-gallery-4.jpg
wget www.[domain].com/images/Photo1.jpg -O 17-hippies-gallery-5.jpg
wget www.[domain].com/images/Savoy-Trio-B&W-resize342x.jpg -O ann-savoy-trio-1.jpg
wget www.[domain].com/images/Baghdaddies-(Small).JPG -O baghdaddies-gallery-1.jpg
wget www.[domain].com/images/Baghdaddies2.jpg -O 17-baghdaddies-gallery-2.jpg
```

So essentially I am creating a wget list of image urls along with a new file name for them. I'm taking the post title, sanitising it, appending -gallery-[number], where the number needs to match the amount of Artist_Title's it has found.

I have this foreach loop, I just need to amend it to add the -[number] based on amount of posts now

```
foreach($gallery as $image) {
    echo 'wget https://www.accessallareas.info/images/' . $image->Gallery_Image_Filename . ' -O ' . sanitize_title($image->Article_Title) . '-gallery.jpg';
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Is this achievable?

Comment: Check if Artist Title is same as previous, if not set counter to 1, if so increment counter.

Comment: that's helpful, thanks! Just stuck at one bit which is probably really obvious, I've got it working so the first multiples work great, but the next set of multiple values continue $i from the previous

Comment: Post that and we'll see.

Comment: I suggest you to create another json where gallery would be arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a counter for each post and check that in your loop.

Try this:

```
$pCounter = 0; // for Post counter
$artistTitle = '';
foreach($gallery as $image) {
    if ($image->Artist_Title !== $artistTitle) {
       $pCounter = 0;
    }
    $counter++;
    echo 'wget https://www.accessallareas.info/images/' . $image->Gallery_Image_Filename . ' -O ' . $image->Artist_Title . '-gallery-'. $pCounter . '.jpg';
    echo '<br>';
    $artistTitle = $image->Artist_Title;
}
```

**Note:**

- You had a typo in your code. `Article_Title` should be `Artist_Title`.
- You need to use `json_decode($json);` at the top of your code to convert JSON into an array of objects.

Comment: That's perfect! My mistake with the typo, you wouldn't believe me if i said how many times I'd written artist..Thanks!

Comment: It happens! :) Feel free to accept it as an answer ;)

Comment: All done! Haha yeah I had
$gallery = json_decode(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/gallery.json'));
Just hadn't posted it in my example ;)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is achievable.

```
$counter = 0;
$article_title = '';
foreach($gallery as $image) {
    if ($image->Article_Title !== $article_title) {
       $counter = 0;
    }
    $counter++;
    echo 'wget https://www.accessallareas.info/images/' . $image->Gallery_Image_Filename . ' -O ' . sanitize_title($image->Article_Title) . '-gallery-'. $counter .'.jpg';
    echo '<br>';
    $article_title = $image->Article_Title;
}
```